# Match a 24 hour formatted time with regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a 24 hour time with regular expressions using egrep.

Here is my test file, test.txt:

```
32:23:31
24:30:31
23:70:31
23:61:31
23:10:70
23:10:61
22:17:16
01:17:15
24:15:22
0:17:16
00:17:17
24:30:31
```

Here is my regular expression:

```
egrep '(2[0-3]|1[0-9]|0[0-9]|[^0-9][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]|[0-9]):([0-5][0-9]|[0-9])' test.txt
```

Resulting matches:

```
23:10:70
23:10:61
22:17:16
01:17:15
00:17:17
```

Any idea why it is matching 23:10:70 and 23:10:61?

Comment: Need end of line marker (usually $) at the end of your regex.

Comment: This might not work with the $ if you were using a log file with other information on the line, so I would recommend using '\>' instead of the '$'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually *matching* `23:10:7` and `23:10:6`, but since you are not using the *end of line* metacharacter `$` at the end of the string, it will process *anything* that follows.

```
egrep '^(2[0-3]|1[0-9]|0[0-9]|[^0-9][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]|[0-9]):([0-5][0-9]|[0-9])$' test.txt
```

In other words, you should only allow `[0-9]` at the end of the string, if the matched digit is the last one on the line, that is, if it is followed by `$`.

Another option, is to force the last digit to be 0-padded if it is less than 10, i.e., instead of `[0-9]` use `0[0-9]`. This will match `23:10:07`, but not `23:10:7`. It's the same you already have for the hours part.

Comment: Good observation.  I added [^0-9] to the end of my regex to get it working.  Thanks!

Comment: What does this part add to the hours validation: |[^0-9][0-9]  ?

Comment: How would you make the ':' optional in this case?