# 24 hour time regex fails to invalidate 3 digit hours

Tags: php, regex, time

I'm trying to validate a 24-hours time `HH:MM` with PHP regular expressions. 
I've found a lot of questions about it, like these:

- [validate this format - "HH:MM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964972/validate-this-format-hhmm)
- [Match a 24 hour formatted time with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438092/match-a-24-hour-formatted-time-with-regex)

but all of them fail to invalidate the 3-digits-hours, like `111:00` (online tester says they match, this is because regexp don't consider the presence of the third digit). Here's an example: https://www.regex101.com/r/cO9aE7/1

How can I correct them to invalidate this case?

Comment: use start and end delimiter ^(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$

Comment: Why not post the regex

Comment: @EdHeal he post regex101 link , it s great too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will match a 24-hour style time as long as it's the only thing in the string:

```
^([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$
```

Alternatively, this one will match a 24-hour time anywhere within a string:

```
\b([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d\b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(2[0-3]|1[0-9]|0[0-9]|[^0-9][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])$
```